# Error : keeps looping

Tags: python, loops

```
def beg():
    if race == "orc":
       print ("You come to the border of the valley but the path splits into two seperate paths one going east and the other going west, there is no indication of which one goes where but you figure you will go one way.")
       print("Your options are: ")
       print("1. left")
       print("2. right")
       time.sleep(10)
       direction1 = input("You decicde to go: ")
       if direction1 == "left":
            print ("You decide to go left towards the snowy forest in which the snow elves live")
       if direction1 == "right":
            print ("You decide to go right towards the desert which is famous of the amount of bandits that are found there.")
       else:
            print ("Please pick one of the listed options")
            beg()
```

Basically the problem I get is that when the code runs and you choose right it works and prints the text but when you pick left it just keeps looping beg()

Comment: For languages where indentation is part of the language, like Python, you should always proofread the code you post so that the indentation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `elif` for the "right" case, so instead of a single chained `if` as you intended, you have two independent `if` statement, the second of which has an `else`.  Just change the "right" test to:

```
elif direction1 == "right":
```

That way you'll skip the `else` if it's "left".